# How to manually or programmatically delete a field?

Tags: 7, entities

I tried creating a field, but my server crapped out halfway with an Internal Server Error due to some spambot attack...

Now, when I try to add the field again, I am getting:

> The machine-readable name is already in use. It must be unique.

I guess some tables were populated in the db. How can I remove these easily?

Comment: Take a look at my answer in http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/46085/programatically-remove-a-field-from-a-node/114946

Answer (score 27, accepted):

You can also use drush to run [`field_delete_field()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!field!field.crud.inc/function/field_delete_field/7). Just run:

```
drush eval 'field_delete_field("yourfield")'
```

Comment: Good call, much cleaner than hunting through the db.  Run cron afterwards too or field_purge_batch().

Comment: This is excellent! FYI that function doesn't completely delete the data. It adds a db table for each field whose name begins "field_deleted_data_". That's probably a good thing. But folks might want to finish the job by dropping those tables.

Comment: Data for deleted fields is purged during cron runs. Please do not drop those tables, as it could WSOD your drupal site.

Answer (score 4):

Wow creating a field takes like 2 seconds ... but if it crapped out, i guess it crapped out.

Since you dont know "where" it crapped out basically you'll have to look for the tables to be sure you clean out whatever IS there ...

- `Drop` the tables `field_data_FIELD_THE_NAME_YOU_GAVE_IT` and `field_revision_FIELD_THE_NAME_YOU_GAVE_IT`.
- Also in `field_config` and `field_config_instance` look for `name` keys (and the `bundle` keys) for the field + bundles you tied the named field to. Delete those entries in those 2 tables as well.
- Clear your site cache.

Comment: Please do not do this. See answer below: field_delete_field() which will invoke any relevant hooks and clean up cache as well. In general, if you are writing SQL or operating directly in the database, you're doing something wrong.

Comment: If the addition of fields failed in the UI. Why would you assume the API will still work to delete malformed data/tables? I agree with your overall reply, I disagree with it for 100% of all cases.

Comment: You're right - i did not thoroughly read the original question. My bad! Preferred method is to use field_delete_field(), but if it fails then going directly to the database is probably the best / only alternative.