# on delete of one field delete other field too

Tags: entities

I want to implement some logic using what I can define that one delete of one field delete other related field.

so is there any module available or anythings else using what I can define cascade delete.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [hook_field_delete](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!field!field.api.php/function/hook_field_delete/7) to determine which field is removed, and if its "yours" - find out which field you need to delete next and [delete it](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/46085/programatically-remove-a-field-from-a-node)

```
function hook_field_delete($entity_type, $entity, $field, $instance, $langcode, &$items) {
   if ($field['field_name'] == 'YOUR_FIELD_NAME') {
       //do some stuff to determine which
       //field you need to delete
       //and delete it 
       //how to remove the field - the link below
   }

}
```

[how to remove the field](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/46085/programatically-remove-a-field-from-a-node)